# Sum of all binary numbers matching a pattern

Tags: algorithms, binary-arithmetic

Given $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots,a_7$ where $a_i \in \{0,1\}$. How to calculate sum of all binary number of the form
$$\over {1a_1a_2*a_3**a_4***a_5a_6a_7}$$

where $*$ represent the position of running digits.

I am thinking about a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: Why dynamic programming? How do you think this problem can be decomposed and solved recursively? What *is* the general problem?

Comment: Is the \over line actually mean something?

Comment: Can you given an example? This would clarify whether $\ast$ stand for a bit, or they stand for either a bit or nothing.

Answer (score 2):

For any such pattern with $i$ stars we have to add $2^i$ numbers. Thus for the contribution of the fixed digits, we can replace the stars by $0$'s and append $i$ $0$'s at the right. For the contribution of the stars, we can replace the fixed digits by $0$'s and the stars by $1$'s and append $i-1$ $0$'s at the right.

For the specific example this gives
$$~~~~1a_1a_2~0~~a_30~0\,~a_4~0~~0~~0~a_5a_6a_7000000~\\
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~1~0~1~\,1\,~~0~~1\,~\,1\,~1~~0~~0~000000~\\
 = 1a_1a_2a_3\overline{a_3}a_4\overline{a_4}\overline{a_4}a_5\overline{a_5a_5a_5}a_6a_7000000.$$

Comment: What if OP mean $*$ can be 0, 1 or *null*

Comment: I applaud this respond is fast and look promising. But the question in its current form is rather unclear.

Answer (score -2):

If $*$ mean $0, 1$ or no digit:
I write a very simple program (sorry, I have trouble with `SHIFT` + `8` and don't want `Crtl` + `V` too much :) )

```
int main(){
    string s;
    int res = 1, pos = 1;
    cin >> s;
    for(int i = 1; i < (int) s.length(); ++i){
        if (s[i] == '0'){
            res <<= 1; // res = 2 x res;
        } else if (s[i] == '1'){
            res <<= 1;
            res += pos;
        } else {
            (res <<= 2) += (res >> 2) + pos;
            (pos <<= 1) += (pos >> 1);
        }
    }
    cout << res;
}
```

I will post the proof later. I need to sleep first.

Comment: Please do post the proof and please replace this C++ implementation with pseudocode.